# Get only few data from hole json answer(all other data not need)

Tags: php, json, api

Using code this code to get responce from other server via api:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://apipage.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Token xxxxxxxx'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $html;
```

as result - getting back json responce:

```
Response headers:
200 success
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: accept, origin, x-requested-with, authorization, content-type
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-length: 1046
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 14:14:51 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: nginx
x-vendon-api-requests: 2


Response data:
{
    "code": 200,
    "result": {
        "id": 3075531,
        "stock_id": 184445,
        "stock_article": "Parfum 2 ml 047 women",
        "selections": [
            {
                "selection": 11,
                "label": "11",
                "price": 1,
                "pricelist": null,
                "pricelist_type": null,
                "payment_device_type": null
            }
        ],
        "type": "PRODUCT",
        "name": "Parfum 2 ml 047 women",
        "units": null,
        "amount": 10,
        "amount_max": 11,
        "amount_standart": 11,
        "amount_critical": 3,
        "refill_unit_size": 1,
        "min_refill": 1,
        "refillable": true,
        "last_purchase": 1624011420,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "recipe": [],
        "ingredient_line": null,
        "critical": false,
        "extraction_time_enabled": null,
        "min_extraction_time": null,
        "max_extraction_time": null,
        "product_price_group": null,
        "has_route_planing_expiry_date": false
    }
}
```

How to grab from all this answer only:
**"name": "Parfum 2 ml 047 women"**
**"amount": 10,**

To echo only them, not whole json answer???
And secon one question, how to run this request not on page load but only after some button press?
And to be sure, i can't change code on second server side to send different responce.
Thank you to all for help.

Comment: With `$decodedJson = json_decode($html, true);` and `foreach($decodedJson as $country) {
    echo 'Item:' .$country['name'].' available '.$country['amount'].'pcs.';
}` i'm getting almost done, but echo result is double `Item: available pcs.Item:Parfum 2 ml 047 women available 10pcs. ` not really understand why and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

We getting responce as JSON, so working with it:

**decoding json**

```
$answer = json_decode($html, true);
```

**Than echo for output**

```
$answer = json_decode($html, true);
echo 'Item:' .$answer['result']['name'].' available '.$answer['result']['amount'].'pcs.';
```

Thank You for all, who was helping.